# D3 tree with predefined depths

Tags: data-visualization, d3.js

I want to create tree with predefined depths with D3.

Is there a way to set depth before tree is generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your definition of “tree”. D3 has [several *hierarchy* layouts](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hierarchy-Layout), of which [d3.layout.tree](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout) is one. The tree layout refers to Reingold–Tilford’s [tidy tree layout](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/tree.html) algorithm. This particular algorithm is not conducive to customizing the depth of nodes because it assumes that all siblings are the same depth (so that it can place the nodes tidily).

The [d3.layout.cluster](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout), in contrast, can be easily modified to render nodes at custom depths. Simply ignore the generated `d.y` coordinate and substitute your own depth value (probably in conjunction with a [linear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) to map from data to pixels). For an example of this technique, see Ken-ichi Ueda’s [right-angle phylograms](http://bl.ocks.org/1036776).